# Call a codebehind function from a javascript method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a codebehind function with javascript. I need to make some operations with my gridview.
Here is my javascript:

```
function hideColumn() {
 var gridrows = $("#GridViewHdcvi tbody tr");
 AddTeklif.RemoveTextBoxes();
 for (var i = 0; i < gridrows.length; i++) {
   gridrows[i].cells[5].style.display = "none";
      }
     return false;
      };
```

And my codebehind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void RemoveTextBoxes()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewHdcvi.Rows)
        {
          TextBox txb = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAdet");
          string adet = txb.Text;
          txb.Visible = false;
          Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("LblAdet");
          lbl.Text = adet+" $";
        }
    }
```

I have an error like 'An object reference is required for the non-static field,method, or property CRM.AddTeklif.GridViewHdcvi' in 'GridViewHdcvi.Rows'. When I make method's name 'public void RemoveTextBoxes()' error gone but method doesn't working since it is not static.

Comment: You cannot access controls of an instance of this page from a WebMethod. You can't even use `(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler`. So either use a postback or try to do it with pure javascript/jquery.

Comment: I had a similar conundrum and, as the others say, I think it's pretty much impossible; if interested, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594884/how-can-i-invoke-a-server-side-event-from-jquery-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing two different concepts.   JavaScript is run from the browser and will not have any access to your server code.   What you are doing here is attempting to call a WebMethod when your page is Rendered to be sent to the browser.

A better approach would be to convert your RemoveTextBoxes method to jQuery as what you are wanting to do is modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would call your JavaScript function hideColumn() from a code behind.

Put this in the method where you want to call your javascript function.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hideColumn", "hideColumn(;", true);
```

To call a codebehind from a javascript function you have to play some tricks.

1.) create a hidden button control.  You have to hide it within the CssClass

```
 <asp:Button ID="hdnButton" runat="server"  CssClass="hidden" />



 .hidden {
     display: none;
 }
```

2.) Create a click hdnButton method in your code behind

3.) Call the hidden button click event from your javascript

```
             function CallCodeBehind() {

                document.getElementById('<%= hdnButton.ClientID%>').click();

                }
```