# How can I loop clicking on a button

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using GeckoFX and a regex in C# to make a YouTube video channel scraper. I want to get the URL of all videos from a selected channel.

I want to use GeckoFX (the Firefox rendering engine) to go to the videos section and click the `Load more` button until every video shows.

I am using this code to click `Load more` over and over:

```
javascript:(function() {

  var LoadButton, IntervalCLB;
  IntervalCLB = setInterval(_clickLoadButton, 100);

  function _clickLoadButton() {
    LoadButton = document.getElementsByClassName('load-more-button');
    if (LoadButton.length > 0) {
      LoadButton[0].click();
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(IntervalCLB);
      alert('Finished - Clicked all "Load More" Buttons.');
    }
  }
})();
```

I want to write something like that in C#.

My code looks like:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

GeckoDocument document = geckoWebBrowser1.Document;

GeckoHtmlElement Male = (GeckoHtmlElement)document.GetElementsByClassName("load-more-button")[0];

if ( Male != null ) {
    Male.Click();
}
```

But that just clicks `Load more` once after one second.

How can I make it loop until the `Load more` button disappears?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518529/how-to-call-a-button-click-event-from-another-method

Comment: So i just add button3.PerformClick(); but the file freezes

Comment: @Borodin dude this is pointless and rude comment. This stuff gives SO bad rep. Question was not how to become programmer and earn millions.

Comment: @Andrey: The question was how to write the equivalent of some JavaScript client-side software in C-sharp. The OP shows some code that *clearly* clicks only once. A solution to the question requires understanding of the JavaScript code and re-implementing it it C-sharp. That's not a trivial job. And because the original JavaScript would contravene any terms of service that I have come across I won't encourage the idea. The question has three downvotes, and I am surprised that you are supporting it.

Comment: @Borodin OP's ToC violations are not your business, but if you really want to be google police then think for a second what kind of damage does simple scrapper for hobby project. It doesn't require Phd in CS to figure out how to port this code to C#. I am supporting this question solemly because this is perfect example how SO is hostile towards newcomers, I am getting tired of defending SO on programming forums of all sorts. Get off your high horse.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
  timer.Elapsed += ( sender, e ) => {

    GeckoDocument document = geckoWebBrowser1.Document;

    GeckoHtmlElement Male = (GeckoHtmlElement)document.GetElementsByClassName("load-more-button")[0];

    if ( Male != null ) {
        Male.Click();
    }
  };
  timer.Start();
```

But from practical side I recommend you to look into YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Comment: You are advocating that the OP breaks the YouTube terms of service, which say [***you agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Website itself, the YouTube Player, or such other means as YouTube may explicitly designate for this purpose***](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms)

Comment: A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else 

And the same is with "e". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Borodin I am not advocating any specific activity, I am linking to **official** development documentation.

Comment: @HamBurg rename sender and e to something else, they are not used in the body anyway. But yeah, I would recommend to get a hand on C# programming book.

Comment: Right. I am going to go deep with c# soon. But for now i still have a problem. I renamed sender and e and now app is running. But when i press the button nothing happens. Do you know why?

Comment: ` public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Timer timer1 = new Timer(1000);
            timer1.Elapsed += (jeden, dwa) =>
            {

                GeckoDocument document = geckoWebBrowser1.Document;

                GeckoHtmlElement Male = (GeckoHtmlElement)document.GetElementsByClassName("load-more-button")[0];

                if (Male != null)
                {
                    Male.Click();
                }
            };
            timer1.Start();


        } `

Comment: @HamBurg maybe there is no button? I can't help you that far. Try to use breakpoints to debug the code.